# Помошник с обновлениями зависимостей в большом проекте

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что большие проекты тяжелы и зачастую зависимости между библиотеками замирают на некотором моменте и почти не обновляются.

Вопрос в следующем: есть ли какой-то уже существующий способ автопроверки зависимостей (с указанием того, что возможно безболезненно обновить) в Python-проектах?

Что такое pipdeptree - знаю, но есть ли аналог (или форк) с уже готовой автоматизацией?

Comment: *"возможно безболезненно обновить"* -- [любое обновление может сломать чей-то workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/). Если у вашего проекта есть тесты, то вы можете проверить ломает ли их обновление и надеяться, что тесты достаточно представительны, чтобы у пользователей слишком много обновление не ломало.

Comment: Речь не про это. Здесь именно про техническую совместимость.

Покрытие тестами очень хорошее и тут скорее нужна массовая проверка зависимостей, чтобы обновление версии одного пакета удовлетворяло всем остальным требованиям. Это можно делать руками, но слишком долго.